# Horizontal alignment of several 'divs' with various text lengths

Tags: html, css

I have 3 identical `divs`  of fixed width. Each contains a text of various lengths and another `div` which **float right**.

When the text are in equal length they auto aligned without any problem. But when the text lengths are different alignment changes drastically. I  have tried to fixed with various settings and non succeeds, I want them to **align horizontally** regardless of text length!

What is missing here?

```css
.con {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #996600;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px, ;
  padding: 0px;
}
.main {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1 class="topic"> Topic goes here </h1>
  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text, short text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text goes here even though it did not work properly, normal length</p>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text goes here, even though it did not work properly, with extra text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting them to be equal height or just align?

Comment: All 'con' 'dives' need to be aligned horizontally..

Comment: just add `vertical-align:top` to `.con`

Comment: @Pete thanks,  it works perfectly..

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just after your `.con` divs aligning horizontally, all you need to do is add `vertical-align:top;` to `.con`:

```css
.con {
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #996600;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px, ;
  padding: 0px;
}
.main {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1 class="topic"> Topic goes here </h1>
  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text, short text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text goes here even though it did not work properly, normal length</p>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text goes here, even though it did not work properly, with extra text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, I missed the `display: inline-block` property were set ... upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `flexbox` to do that, here done by giving the `main` a `display: flex` and setting the `topic` to `width: 100%` so it always will occupy the first row.

```css
.main {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.topic {
  width: 100%;
}
.con {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #996600;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px, ;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1 class="topic"> Topic goes here </h1>
  
  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text, short text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text goes here even though it did not work properly, normal length</p>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text goes here, even though it did not work properly, with extra text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you want the `con` to not wrap, here is a version using a `wrapper` to keep them in 1 line

```css
.main {
  text-align: center;
}
.cons {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 720px;
}
.con {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #996600;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px, ;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1 class="topic"> Topic goes here </h1>
  
  <div class="cons">
  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text, short text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text goes here even though it did not work properly, normal length</p>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para">My text goes here, even though it did not work properly, with extra text</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i'm did through flexbox

```
<div class="main">
  <h1 class="topic"> Topic goes here </h1>
  <div class="con-items">
  <div class="con">
    <p class="para">My text, short text</p>
     <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <p class="para">My text goes here even though it did not work properly, normal length</p>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <p class="para">My text goes here, even though it did not work properly, with extra text</p>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

.con-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.con {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  background: #996600;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.box {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px, ;
  padding: 0px;
}

.con p {
    width: 100%;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/5139we1o/

Answer (score -1):

The solution to your problem is either a hack width negative margins:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

This would lead to equal height boxes and removes unwanted behaviour regarding alignment.

Or as i would suggest a more modern version u try using flex properties:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties -> with this solution you are way more flexible to choose the behaviour of boxes in any particular way and this is a concept definately worth knowing.

I recently used flex to create the same concept as you and i can tell you its the best way to achieve what you want. The only issue with flex is the browser support with IE 11. But still this is the way to do it.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: why down vote my comment, i give the explanation with the possibility to understand not just copy paste